# Springboot with SpringWeb and Webflux Not working

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat, webclient

I am trying to use WebClient in my existing Springboot APP , so Added spring-boot-starter-webflux dependency with spring-boot-starter-web . While calling a rest endpoint and using the block() or subscribe() method, tomcat server is getting stopped and creating a heap dump.

I am running my application in Windows 10 machine in Eclipse IDE.

I have deployed the code in kubernetes and its working there. 
Is there any settings I have to do to run in locally.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe117f87b0, pid=13068, tid=0x0000000000003538
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_202-b08) (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.202-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007ffe117f87b0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


Stack: [0x0000000022f80000,0x0000000023080000],  sp=0x000000002307a3f8,  free space=1000k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00007ffe117f87b0

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.aprMajorVersion()I+0
j  io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.initialize(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z+31
j  io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.initializeTcNative(Ljava/lang/String;)Z+3
j  io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>()V+225
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider.updateDefaultConfiguration()V+110
j  reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider.<init>(Lreactor/netty/tcp/SslProvider$Build;)V+42
j  reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$Build.build()Lreactor/netty/tcp/SslProvider;+5
j  reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientSecure.<clinit>()V+19
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider.defaultClientProvider()Lreactor/netty/tcp/SslProvider;+0
j  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientSecure.<clinit>()V+8
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(Lreactor/netty/http/client/HttpClientConnect$HttpClientHandler;Lio/netty/bootstrap/Bootstrap;Lreactor/core/publisher/MonoSink;)V+50
j  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$$Lambda$800.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+16
j  reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+21
j  reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryPredicate$RetryPredicateSubscriber.resubscribe()V+44
j  reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryPredicate.subscribeOrReturn(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;+32
j  reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+4
j  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+205
j  reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+33
j  reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+39
j  reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Lorg/reactivestreams/Subscriber;)V+71
j  reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block()Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  com.example.demo.service.InfragatewayService.getClli(Lcom/verizon/connect/infra/gateway/model/OrderRequest;)Ljava/util/List;+156
j  com.example.demo.controller.InfraGatewayServiceControllerImpl.sendMsgToPulserTopic(Lcom/verizon/connect/infra/gateway/model/OrderRequest;)Lorg/springframework/http/ResponseEntity;+29
j  com.example.demo.controller.InfraGatewayServiceControllerImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a95c7e85.invoke(ILjava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+42
j  org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+19
j  org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint()Ljava/lang/Object;+19
j  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()Ljava/lang/Object;+19
j  org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(Lorg/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInvocation;)Ljava/lang/Object;+139
j  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()Ljava/lang/Object;+120
j  org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/cglib/proxy/MethodProxy;)Ljava/lang/Object;+133
j  com.example.demo.controller.InfraGatewayServiceControllerImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$69eb2a70.sendMsgToPulserTopic(Lcom/verizon/connect/infra/gateway/model/OrderRequest;)Lorg/springframework/http/ResponseEntity;+36
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 2136  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x0000000002ef55bf [0x0000000002ef5540+0x7f]
J 2135 C1 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (104 bytes) @ 0x0000000002ef5d64 [0x0000000002ef59a0+0x3c4]
J 1756 C1 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (10 bytes) @ 0x0000000002e49e24 [0x0000000002e49de0+0x44]
J 1755 C1 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (62 bytes) @ 0x0000000002e49a24 [0x0000000002e49920+0x104]
j  org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+16
j  org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(Lorg/springframework/web/context/request/NativeWebRequest;Lorg/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+56
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(Lorg/springframework/web/context/request/ServletWebRequest;Lorg/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V+4
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView;+244
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView;+81
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView;+7
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+257
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+212
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+71
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+3
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+149
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+33
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+36
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+304
```

Spring Boot Versions:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

JAVA Code:

```
List<String> clliList = new ArrayList<>();
    webClientBuilder.build()
            .get()
            .uri(builder.toUriString())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ClliInfoResponse.class)
            .doOnSuccess(res ->{    
                System.out.println("I am here - 2" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                clliList.addAll(res.getClliInfoList());
                })
            .doOnError(ex -> ex.printStackTrace())
            .block();
```

Comment: Can you provide the java code making the call ?

Comment: @JamesGawron Updated the question with the code

Comment: So you have this issue only with Eclipse IDE on Windows 10? Do you use embedded JREs or something?

Comment: @Puce I am using the JDK installed in the system not the embedded one , and Yes I am having issue in windows only. Is there anything to do with Admin access ?

Comment: You say tomcat is heap dumping ... but the stack trace indicates that you are using Netty ... if your intent is Tomcat you may want to track down whatever dependency or configuration is causing Netty to be used instead.